# Can I upload a large file via Chrome?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, file-upload, upload

When I try open a file in Chrome, Chrome pops up a file uploader windows, but it shuts down as sson as I choose a file with large volume. It seems that the shutdown limit varies for different web browsers. Is there any method to upload large files? My final goal is to make a HTML form which sends a file chosen from local computer by the user to the back-end server, say, django web application server.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Opera doesn't have upload limit size, so the problem is not Chrome